# PHP - Yii2 Grid View Filter - Add in OR Filter within AND Filter

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

I would like to add in a OR filter within an AND filter.
These are my codes.

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'staffs.email', $this->email])
        ->orFilterWhere(['like', 'users.email', $this->email])
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution!

```
->andFilterWhere(['OR',
                      ['like', 'staffs.email', $this->email],
                      ['like', 'user.email', $this->email]
                 ])
```

Hope this can help someone